# Сервис возвращает 404 с POST запроса

Tags: c#, .net, post, wcf, http-status-code-404

Есть клиент (Windows Phone) и есть REST Service. Проблема вот в чем: я посылаю POST запрос в котором в качестве переменной JSON строка, сервис ее обрабатывает, а ответ приходит :

> "{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: '', Version: 0.0, Content:
>   System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:{  Content-Length: 0}}" Я

Уже очень долго пытаюсь разобраться.Без помощи никак. И так, все по этапам:

1. Переменная которую я отправляю:

   ```
   "{"Category_id":1002,"Country_id":null,"City_id":null,"Areas_id":null,"Gender_user":null,"DateAnnouncing":null,"MinDateBirthday":null,"MaxDateBirthday":null,"Popular":null,"DateSort":null}"
   ```
2. Метод вызова:

   ```
   public static async Task<string> ServiceCalledWithJson( string MethodName, AnnFilter customObject)
   {
       string ServiceURI = GetServiceHost() + MethodName;                                 
       var httpClient = new HttpClient();
       var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { filter = customObject });
       var request = new StringContent(result, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
       var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(ServiceURI, request);
       string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       return content;
   }
   ```
3. В интерфейсе:

   ```
   [OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
   List<Announcing> GetAnnouncingFilter(AnnFilter filter);
   ```
4. Сама функция:

   ```
   public List<Announcing> GetAnnouncingFilter(AnnFilter filter)
   {
       var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filter);
       Logger.WriteToFile_Json(json);
       List < Announcing > listAnnonc = new List<Announcing>();
       Announcing annonc = new Announcing();
       DataTable table = new DataTable();
       table = AnnouncingFilter.GetAnnouncingFilter(filter);
       foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
       {
           try
           {
               annonc.Announcing_id = int.Parse(row["Announcing_id"].ToString());
               annonc.Name_Announcing = row["Name_Announcing"].ToString();
               annonc.Name_City = row["City_Name"].ToString();
               listAnnonc.Add(new Announcing() {Announcing_id=annonc.Announcing_id,Name_Announcing=annonc.Name_Announcing,Name_City =annonc.Name_City });
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Logger.CreateLog(ex);
               throw ex;
           }
       }
       var slem = "";
       slem = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listAnnonc);
       Logger.WriteToFile_Json(slem);
       return listAnnonc;
   ```
5. Логи:

   ```
   {"Category_id":1002,"Country_id":null,"City_id":null,"Areas_id":null,"Gender_user":null,"DateAnnouncing":null,"MinDateBirthday":null,"MaxDateBirthday":null,"Popular":null,"DateSort":null

   [{"Name_City":"Киев","Announcing_id":1,"Name_Announcing":"Прогулки","Phone_Announcing":null,"Date_Announcing":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Info_Announcing":null,"Categories_id":0,"User_id":0,"City_id":0,"Areas_id":null,"AreasOfCity":null,"Categories":null,"Cities":null,"UserList":null,"Favorite_Announcing":[],"Selected_Announcing":[]}]
   ```
6. Web config:

   ```
   <endpointBehaviors>
   <behavior name="restBehavior">
     <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
   </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior" name="Searching.BE.Service.WCFRESTService">
       <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
           contract="Searching.BE.Service.IWCFRESTService"/>
       <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
     <endpoint address="net" binding="netHttpBinding" contract="Searching.BE.Service.IWCFRESTService">
       <identity>
         <dns value="localhost"/>
       </identity>
     </endpoint>
   <webHttpBinding>
     <binding name="webhttp"
       bypassProxyOnLocal="true"
       useDefaultWebProxy="false"
       hostNameComparisonMode="WeakWildcard"
       sendTimeout="10:15:00"
       openTimeout="10:15:00"
       receiveTimeout="10:15:00"
       maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
       maxBufferSize="2147483647"
       maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
       transferMode="StreamedRequest">
       <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                     maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
       <security mode="None">
         <transport clientCredentialType="None">
         </transport>
       </security>
     </binding>
   </webHttpBinding>
   ```

Comment: Было бы неплохо еще и описание REST метода